# Arcane and Fire/Bolt Gems

Tags: bloodborne

In Bloodborne you can buff your weapons with damage scaling, either physical, or elemental. Physical bases damage off three stats: Strength, Dexterity, or Arcane.

When looking at the effects of the Arcane Gems, the [wiki](https://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Arcane+Blood+Gemstone) states:

> If used in in conjunction with a gem that gives bolt or fire damage, the Arcane Blood Gemstone will overwrite the previous gem's effect and replace all damage with Arcane.

So if I have one gem that deals 16% Bolt damage, then I apply a gem that boosts my Arcane Scaling by 15%, does that mean my Arcane scaling goes up by 31% in total?

Answer (score -1):

No, the Arcane damage will cancel the bolt damage and do only arcane damage if you use only flat values gems (ex: +30 Arcane) that adds a flat amount of damage in your weapon as you can see [here](https://fextralife.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-blood-gems/).

But if you put a %elemental gem on a physical weapon the physical damage will be 0 and the weapon will do elemental damage scaling on your arcane values.

the Arcane Scaling gem you have will not boost your bolt damage by 15% but will increase of the 15% the scaling of arcane, so no you won't have +31% fire damage but will increase your damage for the Arcane values of your build.

Now if you want to do a Bolt build i suggest using a good %bolt gem (+23%) and 2 scaling arcane gems like yours, in order to increase the scaling based on your arcane.

Visit [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/41iocl/guide_to_arcaneelemental_weapon_gem_setups/) site for good advices for Arcane/fire/bolt builds.
And [this](https://guidescroll.com/2016/01/bloodborne-arcanist-guide/) for a good Arcane guide

Sorry for the unclarity

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I know the damage type is negated; I have stated that in the original question - what I'm asking is the amount of scaling - is it only the arcane scaling that is applied (i.e. 15%), or arcane *and* lightning (a total of 31%)? Also, if you could provide a source for your findings, that would greatly improve your post!